# Parsing and extracting HTML and Text messages from raw .eml file

Tags: c#, html, email

I did this before, but the source codes were in a flash memory which one failed. So I'm rewriting the project. I've got archived .eml files on disk and I need to extract HTML message if any. If not, I'll extract text message.

I don't remember what 3rd party used before. But parsing was so easy like below:

```
 oMessage.Raw = LoadFile(fileEml);
 msgHTML = oMessage.HTML;
 msgText = oMessage.Text;
```

Can anyone recognize that 3rd party library?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what parsing library you were using before, but the best parser out there right now is [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit). It's significantly faster and more RFC-compliant than any other parser.

I'm also working on a mail client library (SMTP, POP3 and IMAP) called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit).

(Disclosure: I wrote MimeKit and MailKit after spending time looking at all of the Open Source alternatives out there and finding that all of them were really bad, and often the authors of said libraries blamed the other mail software when it was a bug in their own code and they would have realized that if they actually bothered to read the RFCs.)